# how to read string only and ignore other element in JQuery

Tags: jquery, dom, textnode, nodevalue

I have the following 'td'element, and want to read out the string part (cell 1) ONLY without the 'span' part, how can i do that in jQuery?

```
<td class="myTable">cell 1<span class='end'>&emsp;</span></td>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can the information inside the span tag vary? Or does it always follow this pattern with the contents of the span tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a generic solution that will do it without ugly RegExp nastiness :-)

```
var text = $('.myTable').clone()
              .children()
                  .detach()
              .end()
              .text();
```

**Edit 1:**
Alternatively, if you're certain that the `<span>` will always only include some sort of a space character - you could use `.text()` followed by a `.trim()`, like so:

```
$.trim( $('.myTable').text() );
```

**Edit 2:**
Just to play some more, here's another take on a generic solution that doesn't involve jQuery much, and is therefore much more efficient. I present the awesome `.readStringOnly()` plugin:

```
$.fn.readStringOnly = function () {
    var nodes = this[0].childNodes,
        text = '';
    for (var i=0, item; (item = nodes[i]); i++) {
      if ( item.nodeType == 3 ) { // text node! 
        text += item.nodeValue;
      }
    }
    return text;
  };

// Usage:
//   var text = $('.myTable').readStringOnly();
```

This is essentially what the first solution does in pure jQuery methods, but since jQuery provides no support for text-node handling one is left with two fairly bad options: inefficient jQuery code, or this sort of bulky W3C-DOM fugliness. (just as good I made a plugin out of it.)

...

Then again, you could always just use a regular expression as suggested by someone already. :-)

Comment: @Mar Very inefficient in contrast however. =( At the very least, you should replace detach() to remove(). detach() saves the information in the dom... and his question indicates that he wants to get rid of all children contents.

Comment: `.detach()` is sufficient as `.clone()` doesn't clone the data or events by default. Inefficient in comparison? For sure, but a very generic solution for the stated problem.

Comment: @Mar That is valid till you reach Jquery 1.4+ Excerpt from documentation:  Normally, any event handlers bound to the original element are not copied to the clone. The optional withDataAndEvents parameter allows us to change this behavior, and to instead make copies of all of the event handlers as well, bound to the new copy of the element. ---- As of jQuery 1.4, all element data (attached by the .data() method) is also copied to the new copy.---

Comment: for truly efficient, we could loop through .contents() and weed out the `nodeValue`s of the text nodes. :-)

Comment: @Matthew You must have read the docs too fast. Copying events and data is an *off-by-default* option. ...see here: <http://api.jquery.com/clone>

Comment: @Mar Ahh you are correct. I misinterpreted what it was saying. =P

Comment: I'm having way too much fun with this trivial problem. -- Must. Get. Proper. Hobbies.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".myTable").html().replace(/<span.*<\/span>/gi, "")
```

Example here: http://fiddle.jshell.net/TSYQJ/

Comment: Will get my upvote if it is the case that the span tag is the only thing that always is in the td that she would want to remove. Otherwise, it's incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

```
var tableContents = $(".myTable").text();
```

Just tested and this does work. Example page:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert($(".myTable").text()); 
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<table>
<tr>
<td class="myTable">cell 1<span class='end'>&emsp;</span></td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this would also return everything inside span tag as well, in this case the &emsp; character.

Comment: .text() won't work, it returned: cell 1 (then some funky code here because firefox has problem with displaying &emsp;). with .html() i can see it print out: cell 1 <span class='end'>&emsp;</span>. i m more into .remove() or .empty() to get rid of the span element before i call .text(), but seems wont' work either....